# Detecting Oscillations in a Gaussian Curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For a physics simulation tool I am making, I am generating a gaussian pulse and dispersing it. However, there is an issue wherein the dispersed pulse no-longer does not appropriately fit in the time window and has oscillatory behaviour. See the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to be able to tell when this oscillatory behaviour is happening so I can issue a warning.

To briefly explain how it works, here are the steps:

1. Create a gaussian:

```
    def gauss(time, fwhm, center = 0, amplitude = 1):
        sigma = fwhm / (2 * torch.sqrt(2 * torch.log(torch.tensor(2.))))
        pulse = amplitude * torch.exp(-0.5 * ((time - center) / sigma) ** 2)
        return pulse
```

2. Convert the pulse to the frequency domain
3. Disperse the pulse with a quadratic chirp:

```
def quadChirp(ffreqs, signal, chirp_rate):
    phase_shift = chirp_rate * ffreqs ** 2
    chirp_signal = signal * torch.exp(-1j * phase_shift)
    return chirp_signal
```

4. Convert back to time domain

Because I am creating a Gaussian curve and the output is Gaussian, I tried to compare the standard deviation to the time-window which did not give any meaningful results. I've tried a ks test and get the P value = 0. Perhaps there is an elegant solution - am open to any ideas and curious as to what people think!